# Can a Kohen get a divorce?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, divorce, birchas-kohanim

I've always thought the answer was yes, but apparently, I recently heard a different opinion related to whether or not the marriage that the Kohen got into was a legitimate marriage.

Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: We do some additional discouragement as he couldn't remarry his ex-wife. There may be cases where they prefer to find a preexisting flaw in the original marriage to avoid a "divorce" situation. You may have instead heard of a case (these happen) where a woman wants a divorce but still wants to be able to marry a kohen afterwards, so they'd seek to find a pre-existing flaw in the first wedding and void it instead.

Answer (score 8):

A Cohen may divorce his wife.

The Mishna and Halacha mention special rules for the divorce procedures of a Cohen, so it follows that may do so:

For example, in the laws of how to write the names of the husband in a Get (a divorce document) in Shulchan Aruch, Even HaEzer 129:19 - [סימן קכט - דיני שם](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01974_part_5.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2) - it says:

> לֹא נָהֲגוּ לִכְתֹּב בַּגֵּט לֹא כֹּהֵן וְלֹא לֵוִי וְלֹא שׁוּם כִּנּוּי, אֶלָּא: פְּלוֹנִי בֶּן פְּלוֹנִי ...‏

The custom is to not write "Cohen" or "Levi" nor any other accolade in the divorce document. Rather one write *Ploni* son of *Ploni*...

The main divorce restriction a Cohen has, is that he may not marry a divorcee, including his own ex-wife.